# How to append to one specific class amongst multiple class in an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a game, whereby when the page loads or the game is won the 4 color buttons all light up one after the other and then stop (no longer light up). The elements(divs) that I am using as buttons have multiple classes already, including a dynamically attached disabled class to prevent button presses on load up. The 3rd class in each element index[2] contains the color class, e.g. red, green, etc,. I wish to attach '-light' class to those classes, as my 'red-light' class in CSS contains the code to make element 'light up' and then after a minute or so I wish to have that class add-on (-light) removed again??

When a player clicks on a button, I can to exactly this by adding a click function event listener through the following code:

`color = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[2];`

It then passes this to a function that adds and removes the appropriate class like this:

```
$("#"+id).addClass(color + "-light");               
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#"+id).removeClass(color + "-light");
}, 500);
```

However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this just on page load or when user wins??

I tried this so that I could then create a loop to add and remove the color classes but it did not work:

```
const redBtn = $(".red").attr("class").split(" ")[2];
```

I did manage to do something similar for adding and removing the disabled class for the buttons which I have pasted below...

```
function removeDisable() {
 colorBtns.forEach(function (button) {
  button.classList.remove("btn-disabled");
  // console.log(colorBtns);
 });
}
```

Comment: TLDR: Have you looked at `.addClass()` and `removeClass()`?

Comment: Rather than look for "red" then add "red-light" - just add "light" and use css rules to manage, eg `.red.light { background-color: yellow; }`

Comment: @freedomn-m (As I said) TLDR. ;)

Comment: @Scott OP has posted they used addClass and removeClass why post a comment saying you didn't read and then comment asking them to use something that they already tried

Comment: the div itself looks like this: ```<div class="col-md-6 colorBtn red" id="1"></div>``` and then there will be a ```disabled``` class after the 'red' class too?

Comment: @KevinWalton if you stop trying to parse `el.attr("class")` / `el.classList` and utilise jquery - use `$(el).is(".class")` or `$(el).hasClass("class")` with the addClass/removeClass that you're already using - you'll find thinking of the class list as a collection much easier.  There's also no guarantee which order the classes will be in.